# Is this the right code to reuse date and time method? Because I reuse it in three activities

Tags: java, android

I have created DateTime.java class like this:

```
public class DateTime {


public String date() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    return calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)+ "/" + calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/" + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
}

public String time() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    return calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
}

   }
```

in all three activities I get the date and time like this:

```
        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
            dbHelper.insertNote(note, dateTime.date(), dateTime.time(), System.currentTimeMillis());
            finish();
```

Is there any problem with the DateTime class implementation?

Comment: If you don't have a specific problem, you might want to try [codereview.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a new instance of DateTime everytime make your both methods as static. In this way, you will be able to access them directly without creating a new object of DateTime class. This will have negligible effect on your memory because the class is very simple, but it is a good thing to do so that you can use these methods without filling your memory

```
public class DateTime {

   public static String date() {
       Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
       return calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)+ "/" + calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/" + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
   }

   public static String time() {
       Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
       return calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
   }

}
```

to use:

```
dbHelper.insertNote(note, DateTime.date(), DateTime.time(), System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: But is there a reason if I make the two methods private static instead of public static?

Comment: I guess you wont be able access those methods if you make them private. Not sure though. But if you can access them then no issues.